# How would I securely handle paid memberships?

Tags: django, payment-processing

I'm building a simple Django application for a client which will allow for users to register paid accounts to gain access certain parts of the site; however, I've never handled payment processing beyond a few simple Paypal buttons.

My question is, how would I securely handle and verify payments in this situation?

Comment: I dont have an answer but I am very interested to see what the django solution is for this. I would assume "there's an app for that"

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use some of the payment code from Satchmo:

http://www.satchmoproject.com/docs/dev/payment.html